# Error while adding a custom search result component rendering in Sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: sxa

I have created custom search result rendering in Sitecore 9.0.1 using SXA 1.7.But when I add that rendering in the experience editor it shows the below error.

Error Rendering Controller:

```
SearchFeatureCustomization.Controllers.SearchResultCustomComponentController,SearchFeatureCustomization. Action: Index: An unhandled exception occurred.
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.ShowErrorMessage(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, ExceptionArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.Process(ExceptionArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.ExecuteController(Controller controller)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ControllerRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
```

**Log Error:**

```
155144 20:55:16 ERROR Failed to render rendering
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: An unhandled exception occurred.
Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.ShowErrorMessage(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, ExceptionArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.Process(ExceptionArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.ExecuteController(Controller controller)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ControllerRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.FormatException
Message: Input string was not in a correct format.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at SearchFeatureCustomization.Repositories.SearchResultCustomComponentRepository.BookPrice() in D:\CBMM\src\Feature\SearchFeature\SearchFeatureCustomization\Repositories\SearchResultCustomComponentRepository.cs:line 61
   at SearchFeatureCustomization.Repositories.SearchResultCustomComponentRepository.GetModel() in D:\CBMM\src\Feature\SearchFeature\SearchFeatureCustomization\Repositories\SearchResultCustomComponentRepository.cs:line 44
   at SearchFeatureCustomization.Controllers.SearchResultCustomComponentController.GetModel() in D:\CBMM\src\Feature\SearchFeature\SearchFeatureCustomization\Controllers\SearchResultCustomComponentController.cs:line 25
   at SearchFeatureCustomization.Controllers.SearchResultCustomComponentController.Index() in D:\CBMM\src\Feature\SearchFeature\SearchFeatureCustomization\Controllers\SearchResultCustomComponentController.cs:line 31
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.c__DisplayClass24_0.b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

**Below are the steps which I followed:**

1.Created a controller rendering

[image]

2.Repository class

[image]

3.Model class

[image]

4.View

[image]

In Sitecore, I have created a custom rendering and added that to toolbox.

[image]

Can anyone please suggest where I am going wrong and what is the cause for the issue.

Comment: Add full stack trace as a text. Not half of the stack trace as an image

Comment: yes added @MarekMusielak

Comment: I think you haven't pasted inner exception. Check log files

Comment: Now i have added it please suggest @Marek Musielak

Comment: `SearchResultCustomComponentRepository.BookPrice()` it cannot parse int from whatever you're passing there